# PHP split a string and insert in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, ajax

I am using AJAX to send an array of values to a PHP page that will insert the data into MySQL database. The problem is that I am not sure how to split the data into 5 different veriables and loop to insert into DB.

AJAX Request:
Array:

```
[".testimonial", 1119, 316, 1663, 608, "#header", 723, 66, 1663, 608]
```

Posting the array:

Sending Array Parameters using " ; " to split.

```
clicks  
.testimonial;1119;316;1663;608;#header;723;66;1663;608
```

Source Sent:

```
clicks=.testimonial%3B1119%3B316%3B1663%3B608%3B%23header%3B723%3B66%3B1663%3B608
```

PHP Page

```
<?php

$clicks = $_GET["clicks"];
$clickArray = explode(";",$clicks);
$arrays = array_chunk($clickArray, 5);

foreach ($arrays as $array_num => $array) {
  foreach ($array as $item_num => $item) {
    echo "". $item . "<br/>";
  }
}


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "clickmap";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO data (user_id, identifier_name, pos_x, pos_y, window_width, window_height, status)
VALUES ('1', '$postIdentifier', '$postPos_x', '$postPos_y','$postWindowWidth','$postWindowHeight', 'ok')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Current PHP Result:

```
.testimonial
1119
316
1663
608
#header
723
66
1663
608
New record created successfully
```

Comment: What?  Why don't you just send the JSON?  And use the key names in the JSON array to make it easier on the PHP side.

Comment: none of the variables you're using in your query ever get defined. so you're inserting empty strings. and then nothing of your json/array manipulation stuff ever gets used in the query anyways, so it's all useless/pointless code.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I am going to try with JSON now. For some reason I didn't think it would work.   Marc B The question is how to define them when splitting the string and make a loop. Your comment is more useless/pointless than the code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but using `extract` is usually not recommended as it can easily lead to bugs that are hard to debug.

```
$keys = array('postIdentifier', 'postPos_x', 'postPos_y','postWindowWidth','postWindowHeight');

foreach ($arrays as $array_num => $array) {
  $values = array();
  foreach ($array as $item_num => $item) {
    $values[] = $item;
  }
  $data = array_combine($keys, $values);
  extract($data); // now your variables are declared with the right values http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

  // .. run SQL insert here
}
```